# Configure Kibana web page (only) to require a login

Tags: security, login, website, elasticsearch, kibana

I have Elasticsearch 6.4.3 and Kibana 6.4.3 installed on Debian 8 Jessie.

I've looked into `X-Pack` and `Shield`, which both seem to be mostly concerned with security within Elasticsearch, and how to control security *BETWEEN* Elasticsearch and Kibana.

I don't really need security on the backend between Kibana and ES. However we would like the **Kibana web page** to be world accessible with a login page.

Is it possible to implement ONLY a login page for the Kibana site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you want with X-Pack or Shield, but you could use simple nginx configuration above kibana. Example of nginx site config:

```
server {
listen 80;
    server_name kibana.youdomain.com;
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

In this example kibana works on 5601 port.
Also you should add user and password:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -n 'user:' >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users"
sudo sh -c "openssl passwd -apr1 >> /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users"
```

Comment: I think it is possible to configure apache same way as nginx. You should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. The server is currently using Apache (for other sites). I'm assuming this same idea should work for Apache2?